# One cache vs multiple caches

Tags: caching, web-applications, playframework-2.0

I am using the playframework 2 which uses EHcache. Now the api only has `Cache.set` and `Cache.get` so I think there is one big cache.

Wouldn't it be more efficient if there were multiple caches? for examlpe one cache for ip addresses, one cache for usernames etc.

Could you give me some pros / cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the Cache object in Play is to have a generic cache system.

You can specialize caches by extending the actual cache and using specific prefix:

```
class UserCache {

    public static final String PREFIX = "UserCache";

    public static void set(String key, User value) {

        Cache.set(PREFIX + key, value);
    }

    public static User get(String key) {
        return (User)Cache.get(PREFIX + key);

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes I already did a similar approach. But lets say our cache has 1000 entries. And we try to look up a specific user. If the user is not in the cache we would get 1000 misses. If we would have a specific cache with only users, the cache would be much smaller for example 100 entries -> better performance. Or am I wrong?

Comment: For this kind of numbers, the differences are minimal (accessing an in-memory hashmap).

Answer (score 3):

Consider caching in the most general sense. Normally the cache is allowed to grow to some size limit and after that, items are removed from the cache on the basis of the last time they were accessed.

So let's say you want to cache both apples and pears and you've got enough space to hold 20 items in the cache. If you split it up into one cache for apples and another cache for pears, it seems nicely segmented. However, if your customers use a lot of apples but hardly any pears, you'll end up with the apple cache getting full quickly, so apples that have been used recently will be removed from the apple cache, whereas pears that haven't been used for a long time can stay in the pear cache because it's not full.

you can see that if you just had one cache that can store either apples or pears, you're caching the most recently used objects so it's likely to be more efficient overall. So from a performance perspective, you're usually better having as few caches as possible.